# UnicodeEncodeError: how to encode xml tree parsed with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, encoding, utf-8, nltk

I have an XML file with this structure:

```
<doc>
 <content>
  <one>Title</one>
  <two>bla bla bla bla</two>
 </content>
 <content>
  <one>Title</one>
  <two>bla bla bla bla</two>
 </content>
 ...
</doc>
```

I read the file in python through nltk package and parse the tree with ElementTree like this:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
wow = nltk.data.find('/path/file.xml')
tree = ElementTree().parse(wow)
```

Then I try to print something from 'two' elements like this:

```
for i, content in enumerate(tree.findall('content')):
    for two in content.findall('two'):
        if 'keyword' in str(two.text):
            print("%s" % (two.text))
```

And I get the infamous error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know this is due to incompatibility problems with ascii and UTF-8 encodings. The XML encoding is UTF-8. I tried several solutions found here on stackoverflow (mainly: I tried adding `.encode('UTF-8')` or `.decode('UTF-8')` here and there, or also `encoding='utf-8'` added in `data.find`), but the examples I found were quite different from mine, so I didn't manage to adapt those answers to my case: as you can imagine, I am new to python.

How can I avoid the error and print the content I need? Thanks.

Comment: try `if u'keyword' in unicode(two.text):` -- When you call `str` on an object, you coerce that object into string format, which uses the ascii codec. If your object contains non-ascii elements, that will throw an error.

Comment: No need to call `unicode` either -- `two.text` should already be unicode (if it isn't, the decoding needs an explicit codec anyway, and should happen earlier).

Comment: Thanks duhaime and Alex, the `str` was exactly what was causing the problem! I didn't know `str` forced the text in ascii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `two.text` should be a Unicode string and you want to `print` it -- why not just check

```
if u'keyword' in two.text:
```

and then if appropriate

```
print(two.text)
```

without the laborious stringification?  If your terminal is properly set, it will tell Python which encoding to use to send it bytes properly representing that string for display purposes.

It's usually best to work uniformly in Unicode (that's why `str` has become unicode in Python 3:-) and only decode on input, encode on output -- and often the I/O systems will handle the decoding and encoding for you quite transparently.

Depending on your version of Python (which you don't tell us), you **may** need to do some explicit encoding -- as soon as possible, not late in the day.  E.g, if you're stuck with Python 2, and `wow` is a Unicode string (depends on your version of `nltk`, I think), then

```
tree = ElementTree().parse(wow.encode('utf8'))
```

might work better; if `wow` is already a utf8-encoded byte string as it comes from nltk, then obviously you won't need to encode it again:-).

To remove such doubts, `print(repr(wow[:30]))` or thereabouts will tell you more.  And `print(sys.version)` will tell you what version of Python so you can in turn tell us, as so few people appear to do even though it's most often absolutely crucial info!-)

Comment: The error seems to be pointing to line 3 though, so wouldn't that imply the `str()` call is causing the problem?

Comment: @duhaime sure, the `str(...)` happens before the equivalent `%` formatting in the `print` -- both try to encode `two.text` as ascii.  And neither is necessary!  See my answer: no `str` call, no `%` in `print` either.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell, my python version is 2.7 and cutting `str` worked perfectly! The problem is I was using and adapting code taken from nltk book, I thought `str` was crucial, and it wasn't. Thanks!